# Is there any form of youtube-startup partnership?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any youtube-startup partnership that may offer a customized youtube API to startups?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean like a special treatment where they provide you special methods/functions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a specific software development question.

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. Special methods/functions... I need several API methods that were deprecated recently and am not sure about how feasible is a personal implementation. Mainly my issue is with the user's watched history...

Answer (score 1):

Youtube API is open to all. There is currently no customized [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) for certain group of people. If certain features are not existing, you can either file a [feature request](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82314/is-there-a-standard-place-to-make-youtube-feature-requests) or create your own implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, What I wanted is to access is the user's watched history and as you know this feature is not available as off last sept. Do you have any idea about how to create a new implementation? I have no clue. Thanks again!

Comment: The up-to-date API method that returns "watch history" is [PlaylistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) which returns a  [watch history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource) resource. I haven't personally played around with it yet so that's far as I can share for now.